# how spring data jpa repository.save only do update

Tags: spring-data-jpa

How `spring-data-jpa repository.save` only do `update` but NOT create new one if primary key is not found.
Currently, repository.save() will create a now record in my database if not found

Answer (score 33):

`Repository.save()` is a dual purposed method for *Insert* as well as *Update*

There are two mechanisms used by Spring to decide if it must use *Insert* or *Update* on an entity:

1. By default, Spring inspects the **Id-Property** (`@Id`) of the entity, to figure out if the entity is new or not. If the identifier property is null,     then the entity is treated as **new**, else not new.
2. Another way to take better control of this is by implementing
   `Persistable`. For entities that implement `Persistable`, Spring
   will call `isNew(…)` method to figure out if it must be *Inserted* or *Updated*.

Comment: could you tell me how to implement it ?

Comment: What are you looking to implement? `save()` operation is implemented by Spring Data JPA framework.

Comment: I mean let 'save' operation only do update, but not do create

Comment: Use findOne, and then use save with ID.

Comment: I don't see any save with ID, can you please show an example? @ManishMaheshwari

Comment: How can i do it as atomic action? i mean how can find one and update (with save()) can be thread safe?

Comment: checking and saving will not be atomic. If a delete happens in between , the save will do insert. How to prevent this insert ?

Comment: I wanted to do `EntityManager.persist()` only, and not the `EntityManager.merge()` that Spring Data `JpaRepository.save()` uses. Thus, I implemented the `Persistable` interface. This post was the only documentation I found to solve this problem, so I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

@ManishMaheshwari meant Repository.findeOne(Id).
Here is an example of a controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/recipes/{id}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String saveEditedRecipe(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
    Recipe recipe = recipes.findOne(id);

    //do anything you want

    recipes.save(recipe);

    return "redirect:/recipes/" + recipe.getId();
  }
```

I this case we are getting existing Id value from path and passing it in the .findOne(). This way we getting recipe with correct Id we want to update. Then you can do extra logic or just .save(). Using this approach it will update the entity with Id you passed in for sure.